# JButton array ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jbutton, actionlistener

In short, I would like to accumulate a bunch of `JButton`'s to an array, and create one `ActionListener` class for the array.

I'm trying to create a calculator, and all the numbered buttons, such as "6", are in a `JButton` array, because I would like to have it input the set number into a temporary int, and it would be easier to create one method, instead of 10. I also have 40 other buttons, that I would like to apply the same principal to, but in a different array, so it would be much faster and easier to put these into a couple of `ActionListener` methods where the buttons data is implemented to that method.
this is the code I have:

```
private JButton num0, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9;
private JButton numArray[] = {num0, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9};

        public GUI(){
          numArray.AddActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

             }
       });
  }
```

Comment: You need to use loops.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can consider the proposal of Newb Monad. However, you can use the same listener for all your buttons, as in the following example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                String text = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
            }
        }
    };

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,3));

    JButton[] array = new JButton[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
        array[i].addActionListener(listener);
        panel.add(array[i]);
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

}
```

[image: Dialog]

[image: Event]

Comment: this, `String text = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();` can be replaced by `String text = e.getActionCommand();` 1+

Comment: Yes I had thought of this.Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea. However, array objects do not have an `addActionListener()` method. You *must* add an action listener to each `JButton` individually. You can use the same listener for every button, but then you have to figure out which button was clicked inside the `actionPerformed()` method. IMO, a cleaner solution is to assign a separate listener to each JButton because that way each ActionListener can know which number is pressed without checking the source of the event. For example, you can create a `NumberButtonListener` class which takes an `int` as the only argument to its constructor. You can then create the JButtons and the corresponding `NumberButtonListener`s at the same time in a small loop.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well for me.
I essentially loop through all of the buttons while checking it against the action (e.getSource()).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    //loop through allbuttons to check if clicked
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonArr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < buttonArr[0].length; j++){
            if(e.getSource() == buttonArr[i][j]){
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a 2D array of buttons for a game of "Connect Four". I was able to use a for loop inside ActionListener to test which of my buttons had been pushed. The key was modifying the toString() method from my button class to supply the array element as a string:

Within the JPanel class definition:
...

```
discs = new RoundButton[6][7]; //my 2D array
```

...

```
public class RoundButton extends JButton {
...
    public String toString() {
        return "discs["+i+"]["+j+"]";
    }
...
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    for (int i = 0; i < discs.length; i++){
        for (int j= 0; j < discs[i].length; j++){
            if (event.getSource() == discs[i][j]){
                discs[i][j].setIcon(yellowDisc); //my particular action for that button
            }                                       
        }
```

Sorry this is messy. I've never posted on here before.